# Javascript base64 encode

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64

I have a this credential:

```
username: pippo
password: 1234\zxcv
```

I need to generate base 64 encoding. The correct base 64 string is

I use btoa() but not convert correctly string. 
The problem is \ character. Ho can I escape it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape `\` with `\\` when user inputs `\` character.

```html
<form>
username: <input type="text" /><br />
password: <input type="password" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
  var input = document.querySelector("input[type=password]");
  input.oninput = function(e) {
    if (e.target.value.slice(-1) === "\\") {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/\\/g, "\\");
    }
  }
  
  document.querySelector("input[type=submit]")
  .onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(btoa(input.value), atob(btoa(input.value)));
  }
</script>
```